# Interfacing Qt program with third-party program - how to send information between them?

Tags: c++, qt

My ultimate goal is to develop an interface tool for microcontroller development that allows for information to be relayed between device and computer. I am developing a Qt gui that will graphically display information that a `libusb` program sends to it.

I have developed the Qt gui I'll be using that will display this information. Additionally, the gui has a *send* button that will do the opposite and pass strings to other programs developed independently. So, in short, what are the steps to getting something like this to work:

`- Qt gui send commands to someProgram`

`- someProgram responds`

In the context of a basic echo program I understand a simple secondary program will simply take a few string arguments using, depending on your language, something like `main(int argc, char *argv)`. It would be relatively simple to just take these strings and send them back.

However, I am confused on how to accept and send these run-time arguments using the Qt framework. I imagine there to be little differences regarding *sending* parameters to other programs at run-time, but I am not sure where to being with regards to *receiving* them.

**summary: how to send and receive arguments from third-party programs using the Qt framework**

Comment: It very much depends on the other program. Are you developing the other program (such that you can you can choose/define the communication method) or do you have to use it as-is (in which case you will have to conform to the interface it presents)?

Comment: I am actually developing both programs, so I am free to implement the communication in any way.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: why would you develop own methods?!

Answer (score 3):

In general you could use networking, shared memory, or memory mapped files. Qt provides some more specific information on your options for [inter-process communication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can choose among several ways, but please note that things have changed between Qt 4 and Qt 5 in this regard, so you better focus on Qt 5 rather than Qt 4. From the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/ipc.html):

TCP/IP

> The cross-platform Qt Network module provides classes that make network programming portable and easy. It offers high-level classes (e.g., QNetworkAccessManager, QFtp) that communicate using specific application-level protocols, and lower-level classes (e.g., QTcpSocket, QTcpServer, QSslSocket) for implementing protocols.
>   Shared Memory
>
> Shared Memory
>
> The cross-platform shared memory class, QSharedMemory, provides access to the operating system's shared memory implementation. It allows safe access to shared memory segments by multiple threads and processes. Additionally, QSystemSemaphore can be used to control access to resources shared by the system, as well as to communicate between processes.
>   D-Bus protocol
>
> D-Bus protocol
>
> The Qt D-Bus module is a Unix-only library you can use to implement IPC using the D-Bus protocol. It extends Qt's Signals and Slots mechanism to the IPC level, allowing a signal emitted by one process to be connected to a slot in another process. The Qt D-Bus documentation has detailed information on how to use the Qt D-Bus module.
>   QProcess
>
> QProcess
>
> The cross-platform class QProcess can be used to start external programs as child processes, and to communicate with them. It provides an API for monitoring and controlling the state of the child process. QProcess gives access to the input/output channels of child process by inheriting from QIODevice.
>   Session Management
>
> Session Management
>
> In Linux/X11 platforms, Qt provides support for session management. Sessions allow events to be propagated to processes, for example, to notify when a shutdown occurs. The process and applications can then perform any necessary operations such as save open documents.